# How to use a list to print out a sentence in Python

Tags: python

I have this list of data

```
[
    {"type": "Square", "area": 150.5},
    {"type": "Rectangle", "area": 80},
    {"type": "Rectangle", "area": 660},
    {"type": "Circle", "area": 68.2},
    {"type": "Triangle", "area": 20}
]
```

I want to define an object to represent this data, which takes the values from 'type' and 'area' and store it in a class (I call this class Object).

Here is what I tried to do:

```
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list
```

Then from this class I want to print out type and area for each object in the class.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code.

Comment: Do you want it to print it or store it in some variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print it then use `f string`

```
listt = [
    {"type": "Square", "area": 150.5},
    {"type": "Rectangle", "area": 80},
    {"type": "Rectangle", "area": 660},
    {"type": "Circle", "area": 68.2},
    {"type": "Triangle", "area": 20}
]

for i in range(len(listt)):
    print(f'{i+1}- {listt[i]["type"]} with area size {listt[i]["area"]}')

>> 1- Square with area size 150.5
   2- Rectangle with area size 80
   3- Rectangle with area size 660
   4- Circle with area size 68.2
   5- Triangle with area size 20
```

Comment: `['{} - {type} with area size {area}'.format(i, **el) for i, el in enumerate(listt, 1)]`

Comment: He wants to print it. Dont want to store in list..

Comment: Yes, I know, I just used list comprehension as short form of loop to show you that using `enumerate()` and `str.format()` could make your code look better *(imho)*

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. You should try to figure out such things first by yourself.

```
for idx, val in enumerate(your_list, start=1):
    print(f'{idx} - {val["type"]} with area size {val["area"]}')
```

Comment: `print('{} - {type} with area size {area}'.format(idx, **val))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght why do you prefer `.format()`? For me it's not as readable ^^"

Comment: you could use start=1 argument in enumerate

Comment: @c0mr4t, I used it because it accepts keyword arguments, so you can just unpack dict instead of get each value separately.

Comment: @OlvinRoght ya okay, I guess thats just personal preference. But I see your point.